# Could somebody please create the [router] tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I just submitted a question with regards to networking. A router is involved. Unfortunately, there is no router tag, only a route tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to disagree with the need for a router tag, your question has nothing to do with the router, it's just an additional detail. Tags have gone under several major changes - in this case [router](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/router) would be considered more a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), which wouldn't add any additional value to your post. Instead I've added the [file-sharing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/file-sharing) tag which seems to be more in-line with your ultimate goal.

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks.